# defaultValue in migration doesn't work

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations

I have an MVC project with EF and code-first.

I have a model PropBase and a model MyProp - and they are mapped to the same table (with an automatically "Discriminator" column).

I added two properties to MyProp - prop1 and prop2:

```
   public class PropBase
   {
       public double Prop0 { get; set; }
   }

   public class MyProp: PropBase
   {
       public double Prop10 { get; set; }
       public double Prop1{ get; set; }    // new property
       public int Prop2{ get; set; }       // new property
   }
```

And I also added a new migration:

```
    public partial class AddProps12 : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            AddColumn("dbo.Props", "Prop1", c => c.Double(nullable: true, defaultValue: 0));   
            AddColumn("dbo.Props", "Prop2", c => c.Int(nullable: true, defaultValue: 0));
        }

        public override void Down()
        {
            DropColumn("dbo.Props", "Prop1");
            DropColumn("dbo.Props", "Prop2");
        }
    }
```

but when I run the application - the new columns are added with **null** and on the line

```
  return m_myPropsRepository.AsQueryable().ToList();
```

I get this error

> The 'Prop1' property on 'MyProp' could not be set to a 'null' value.
>   You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'Double'.

I can't use nullable:false, because when I insert a new PropBase to the table - it doesn't know Prop1 and Prop2 and therefore inserts NULL and then I get an error because I defined it as non-nullable.

I need a way to do it nullable **AND** to put 0 as default value to the current MyProp rows.

Comment: What does mean 'Anyway I need it as true because PropBase is in the same table and does not contain prop1 + prop2'

Comment: table Props contains PropBase rows AND MyProp rows. PropBase does not have properties prop1 and prop2, therefore the columns of prop1 and prop2 must be nullbale. It work perfect with prop0 and other models I have  - but with those models the table was created with CodeFirst and not with manual migrations.

Comment: Omg, are you using 2 entities for one table ?

Comment: Of course. I use it all the time. It's very easy with CodeFirst. EntityFramework just adds "Discriminator" column automatically so it knows what type is every row.

Comment: @Mike - look here http://www.techiesweb.net/entity-framework-code-first-inheritance-table-per-hierarchy-and-table-per-type/

Comment: Oh, sorry I misunderstood you.

Comment: can you post your first migration ?

Comment: No, it was automatic migration, I don't have this code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try

```
AddColumn("dbo.Props", "Prop1", c => c.Double());   
AddColumn("dbo.Props", "Prop2", c => c.Int());
Sql("UPDATE dbo.Props SET Prop1 = 0, Prop2 = 0 WHERE Discriminator = 'MyProp'");
```

The idea is to update with not null value the old values from DB table with Discriminator "MyProp"

Comment: Actually it need to be added with null, but EF must not map it.
All fields except primary key must be nullable in DB.

Comment: @TamarG Please delete old values from DB table with Discriminator "MyProp"

Comment: I can't do anything manually because it's gonna be install on other computers too.

Comment: Thanks!! At last someone understood me :) This is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Ok... Use like below

```
AddColumn("dbo.Props", "Prop2", c => c.Int(nullable: false, defaultValue: 0));
```

set nullable:false in your code

Comment: When I write "nullable: false" and "defaultValue:0 " it works for the current row, but when I'm trying to add a new PropBase row to the table - I get an error because it inserts NULL to Prop1 and Prop2 (PropBase does not know Prop1 and Prop2). I need a way to do it nullable AND to put 0 as defaultValue to the current MyProp rows

Answer (score 0):

You added the two fields as nullable in the db (nullable: true) but your model (object) has these type declared as non nullable. So EF is trying to assign a null value to non nulalble properties. Make the object properties nulallbe like so:

```
public class MyProp: PropBase
{
   public double Prop10 { get; set; }
   public double? Prop1{ get; set; }    // new property
   public int? Prop2{ get; set; }       // new property
}
```

Or you must make the columns non nullalbe (nullable: false) in the database.

If you want it nullable but still need a default value of 0 then you can do something like this:

```
public class MyProp: PropBase
{
 private double? _prop1;
 private double? _prop2;

 public double Prop10 { get; set; }
 public double? Prop1
 {   
    get
    {
        if(!this._prop1.HasValue)
            this._prop1 = 0;

        return this._prop1;
    }
    set
    {
        this._prop1 = value;
    } 
 }
 public int? Prop2
 {   
    get
    {
        if(!this._prop2.HasValue)
            this._prop2 = 0;

        return this._prop2;
    }
    set
    {
        this._prop2 = value;
    } 
 }    
}
```

Comment: Did you rerun the migration after changing it to false?

Comment: yes. Anyway - nullable:false doesn't help me. I need this column to be nullable because this table is also for PropBase too, and PropBase doesn't use prop1 and prop2. Prop0, for example, is now nullable in the table (I used automatic migrations).

Comment: Then you have to make your object properties nullable. Specifying a default value will only work if the column (in the db) is marked as not nullalbe. If you mark the columns as non nullable and specify a default value then PropBase does not need to have them. EF is complaining that there is a type mismatch between the db column type and the property type of the object. Both need to be not nullalbe or both must be nullable.

Comment: If I write "nullable: false" and "defaultValue:0 " it works - but when I'm trying to add a new PropBase row to the table - I get an error because it insert NULL to Prop1 and Prop2 (PropBase does not know Prop1 and Prop2).

Comment: I need a way to do it nullable AND to put 0 as defaultValue to the current MyProp rows .